# How to make chevron down clickable

Tags: css

I want to bring the dropdown chevron behind my dropdown so that when I click anywhere on my dropdown, I can see the menu. Right now the chevron-down area is unclickable.

I have looked into other options of using font awesome but have not been able to do so.

```
  <div id="actions-dropdown" class="actions">
      <select class="select-option" required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
          <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
      </select>
      <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.select-option {
    background: transparent;
        background-size: auto auto;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px white solid;
    margin: 11px 0px 0px 1071px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.fa-chevron-down {
    color: red;
    z-index: -5;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;
}
```

Method 2 using Font Awesome

```
.select-option {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 40px;    
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background:black;
}

select{       
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;       
  width: 240px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.select-option:after {
  content:"\f078";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background: : black;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;      
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your markup like this. use `label` instead of `i`. set `pointer-events: none` to `.fa-chevron-down`

```
   <div id="actions-dropdown" class="actions">
          <select id="select-el" class="select-option" required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
              <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
          </select>
          <label id="arrow" for="select-el" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></label>
      </div>
```

```css
.select-option {
    background: transparent;
        background-size: auto auto;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    margin: 11px 0px 0px 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
.actions {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.fa-chevron-down {
    color: red;
    z-index: 7;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:0;
    pointer-events:none;
}

.select-option {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 40px;    
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background:black;
}

select{       
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;       
  width: 240px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.select-option:after {
  content:"\f078";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background: : black;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;      
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
 <div id="actions-dropdown" class="actions">
          <select id="select-el" class="select-option" required>
              <option class='option'>option</option>
              <option class='option'>option</option>
              <option class='option'>option</option>
              <option class='option'>option</option>
          </select>
          <label  for="select-el" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></label>
      </div>
```

Comment: I changed it to a label but still the area with the chevron is unclickable. Do I need to make any changes to css?

Comment: i give demo in 5 min

Comment: While this works, I am trying to avoid using a link in my html. I was able to get it to work with the link but I am trying to find a method without the link.

Comment: what do you mean my that @Maddy ?

Comment: the link "<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>" is what I dont want to use in my html. There are few reasons which I cannot disclose on why I cannot use a link in my program.

Comment: this only for demonstration. you can download font awesome in locally and use that. or you can use an only necessary icon of it using https://icomoon.io/

Comment: if you only use font awesome this puricluar icon. then don't use dara-image or svg icon instead

Answer (score 0):

Case 1) `z-index: -5;` might be your problem.

```
.fa-chevron-down {
    color: red;
    z-index: -5;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;
}
```

Case 2) `.select-option:after` not sure if this works because form elements don't have pseudo elements like :before and :after. You might need a different element, like a `span` to wrap the `<select>` element and apply `:after` to `span`.